# What second jquery .change() gives in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking for .change() examples in select dropdown menus, and found this:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-selectbox

why is it:

```
$(selector).change(function(){}).change()
```

instead of just

```
$(selector).change(function(){})
```

Comment: The first one will trigger `change` event as soon as script loads

Comment: `.change()` is shorthand for `.trigger('change')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they want to add the handler, and fire the event immediately.

`.change()` with no arguments will fire the `onchange` event.

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer.